# trying to counteract asynchronous code execution error

Tags: javascript

I am making this code right here which gets every for the past 30 days and pushes each date to an array. Then in the for each function, I am looking at each date and finding a second date (which is the last minute before midnight).

I then run the code to my database and `date` is an array of objects that were between the two dates that I gave it. This part works...

I have some problem with this codes asynchronous execution. It delivers different outcomes when refreshing the page.

```
            var today = new Date();
            var dates = [];
            var datesSimple = [];
            var counts= [];
            //console.log("today " + today)
            var year = today.getFullYear();
            var month = today.getMonth();
            var date = today.getDate();
            //console.log(dates);
            for(var i=30; i>0; --i){
                var day=new Date(year, month, date - i);
                //console.log(day);

                dates.push(day);
                datesSimple.push((day.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + day.getDate() + '/' +  day.getFullYear());
                if(i === 1){
                   var d = new Date();
            d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
            dates.push(d);
            //console.log(dates.length);

            datesSimple.push((day.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + (day.getDate()+1) + '/' +  day.getFullYear());
            var counter = 0;
            dates.forEach(function(date) {
                var tempDate = new Date(date);
                tempDate.setHours(23,59,59);

                var MatchmadeApps = Parse.Object.extend("matchMadeApps");
                var query = new Parse.Query(MatchmadeApps);
                query.greaterThan("createdAt", date);
                query.lessThan("createdAt", tempDate);
                query.limit(1000);
                query.find({
                    success: function(data) {
                        counts.push(data.length);
                        counter++;

                        if(counter === dates.length){
                            for(var i = 0; i<dates.length; i++){

                            }
                            console.log(counts);
                            console.log(dates);
                            var canvas = document.getElementById('updating-chart'),
                                                    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
                                                    startingData = {
                                                    //x-axis data
                                                      labels: datesSimple,
                                                    //y-axis data
                                                      datasets: [
                                                         /* {
                                                              //data set 1
                                                              fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                                                              strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                                                              pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                                                              pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                                                              data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
                                                          },*/
                                                          {
                                                              //data set 2
                                                              fillColor: "rgba(45, 158, 126,0.2)",
                                                              strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                                                              pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                                                              pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                                                              data: counts
                                                          }
                                                      ]
                                                    },
                                                    latestLabel = startingData.labels[6];

                                                // Reduce the animation steps for demo clarity.
                                                var myLiveChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(startingData, {animationSteps: 15});


                                                setInterval(function(){
                                                  // Add two random numbers for each dataset
                                                  //  myLiveChart.addData([Math.random() * 100, Math.random() * 100], ++latestLabel);
                                                    // myLiveChart.addData([Math.random() * 100], ++latestLabel);
                                                  // Remove the first point so we dont just add values forever
                                                    //myLiveChart.removeData();
                                                    //300000 ms is 5 minutes
                                                }, 1800000);
                            //console.log(counts);
                            //console.log(dates);
                        }
                    }
                });

            }); 
                }
            }
```

Comment: I've always done the same thing in these situations: use a counter. Also interested if there's a better way...

Comment: You can have an if statement based on the condition `counts.length === dates.length`. If the query fails or produces and error, this condition and your current counter condition will fail. Also, we can't use the index forEach loop as the order of the callback is not guaranteed.

Comment: For some reason, the last 4 or 5 outcomes in counts keep coming in different orders